# Statically linking GTK+ libraries in windows

Tags: gcc, static-libraries, gtk

I have installed GCC and GTK+. Its working fine, but i need to statically link GTK+ libraries with my application (it's a small application) so that there exist only one '.exe'.

Answer (score 6):

[mingw-cross-env](http://mingw-cross-env.nongnu.org/) has fixes to build gtk and all related libs statically

Answer (score 5):

It is supported with a few minor issues (like having trouble finding configuration files), but you will have to compile GTK+ yourself! (the default binaries do not include static libraries)

See [this mailing-list thread](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-app-devel-list/2003-September/msg00024.html) for more information on this issue.

Comment: No, it is not. Read the full thread you linked, expecially the Tor Lillqvist comments (mantainer of the windows port).

Comment: Tor points to two issues: Gtk+ finding 2. its message catalogs, and 1. its configuration files. To avoid configuration files, you can hard-code your configuration in the program, with calls to gtk_rc_parse_string. For the message catalogs, you can ship with them if you accept to loose internationalization.


So, while not a perfect solution, it can be hacked.

Comment: These are not little issues and the thread was pure theoretical discussion. Anyway with the current GTK+ codebase (and this includes the build system) it is **not** possible. Otherwise, please, point me out to a single application linked against a GTK+ static library.

Comment: I have built some statically-linked, relocatable apps on my mac (against Gtk+-2.10, without i18n). It requires hacking, but it is not impossible.

Comment: In maths, proofs of inexistence are sometimes easier than proofs of existence. In real life, though...

Answer (score 4):

The correct answer would be two words: `not supported`. Really, if you want to distribute your application, being it 2 or 100000 lines, just bind a copy of GTK+ with it.