# .dll files required to run .exe file on other computers (c, gtk3)

Tags: c, dll, gtk3

I have an application that is written in c, compiled with gcc (mingw), on windows 7 64bit. and it uses gtk3 libraries.

I intend to make it a standalone file, portable application, that wouldn't require anything to be pre-installed, nor installed.

if I try to run it on other machines, it fails to launch "some-gtk-library.dll is missing"

I suspect that putting all the missing .dll files in the same folder would make the program run, but I want to know how can I integrate all the needed files in the .exe file

**EDIT 1**

here is the error I get if I try adding the option `-static` in the linking stage of gcc

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgtk-3
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdk-3
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib\libgobject-2.0.a(libgobject_2_0_la-gtype.o):(.text+0x99b0): multiple definition of `DllMain'
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib\libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.a(gdk-pixbuf-io.o):(.text+0x1f10): first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You sure can, if you link them statically. They will then be embedded in your executable, so you won't need to ship them. Of course, there are downsides: larger executable size and possible licensing issues (GPL). You should consult GTK docs to find out how to do that.

Comment: for example if I want to import "libcairo-2.dll" what should I do ?

Comment: Why don't you take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875855/statically-linking-gtk-libaries-in-windows

Comment: I found a static gtk3 but it's for win32, and it's an old version, so it won't compile nor link... I already saw this question and still can't find any gtk3 win64 static libs, I would appreciate some help