# How to statically link GTK 3.20 with my program on Windows

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

I would like to statically link GTK 3.20 library with my program so i could have a final standalone (.exe) file without need to distribute GTK 3.20 DLLs .

- Programming language : C
- Library : GTK 3.20
- IDE : Code::Blocks
- OS : Windows 7 x_86

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Statically linking GTK+ libraries in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875855/statically-linking-gtk-libraries-in-windows)

Comment: Not fully explained there .

Comment: It is explained for linux there , plus , i'm on windows / code blocks

Comment: You just shouldn't statically link, it isn't supported and will only end in pain. There is nothing wrong with bundling files in a directory with a nice installer.